# I can't download anything after trying to install skype

Tags: 12.04, skype

I keep getting this error whenever I try to download something or open up software center : The package skype:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it. I am a new to ubuntu and I don't know how to fix it please help!

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us the method in which you tried to install Skype. Was it a downloaded tarball, a .DEB file or some other process? Details are a must.

Comment: I downloaded i through their website it was a .deb file I installed it and at the same time I was programming and I ran some code and the it froze the computer and I tried exiting out but I ended up having to shut it of and there was this red icon at the top bar that tells me skype:i386 needs to be re installed I can't run the update program or the software center

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. You can force it by using dpkg. I hope it solves the issue for you as well.

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all skype
```